# sql condition multiple condition when column a =! column b BUT with exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, notin

How to write query for such case

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell ABC | 1 |
| Cell oo | bb |
| Cell BCD | 2 |
| Cell bb | oo |

I need to meet conditions :

Show me only  results of Column A and B when they differs BUT with exception when
Column A = 'oo' and Column B = 'bb' or Column A = 'bb' and Column B = 'oo' i don't want them in my results (they have exception)

Based on this example i expect to see in results only

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Cell ABC | 1 |
| Cell BCD | 2 |

I tried query

```sql
Select * from Table where Column A ! = Column B
```

but I am stuck with part to exclude when columns have particular values.

Comment: I would expect to see all the rows; there are no rows, for example, where `Column A = 'oo' and Column B = 'bb'` is true as there are no rows where `ColumnA` has the value `'oo'`. `'oo'` <> `'Cell oo'`.

Comment: `where columnA <> columnB and not (columnA = 'Cell bb' and columnB = 'oo' or columnA = 'Cell oo' and columnB = 'bb')`

Comment: I'm not clear about the actual data regarding the "Cell" prefix: `where columnA <> columnB and (columnA not in ('Cell bb', 'Cell oo') or columnB not in ('bb', 'oo'))`

Comment: Either of those will work as long as nulls are not present.

Comment: What in case if nulls values appear ?

Comment: If the columns can contain null values, add some nulls to your sample data and adjust the expected result if needed.

Comment: Actually the first condition would eliminate nulls appearing in either of thr columns. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can try those conditions :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (
      columnA <> columnB 
      AND NOT (columnA = 'bb' and columnB = 'oo' 
               or columnA = 'oo' and columnB = 'bb')
      ) OR columnA IS NULL OR columnB IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
create table mytable (
  ColumnA   varchar(20),
  ColumnB   varchar(20)
);

insert into mytable values
('ABC', '1'),
('oo',  'bb'),
('oo',  NULL),
(NULL,  'bb'),
(NULL,  NULL),
('BCD', '2'),
('bb',  'oo');
```

Outputs :

```
ColumnA ColumnB
ABC     1
oo      null
null    bb
null    null
BCD     2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/s0r0PU8e)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the condition to exclude the records and then negate them with `NOT` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  COLUMN_A <> COLUMN_B
AND    NOT ((COLUMN_A = 'oo' AND COLUMN_B = 'bb') 
             OR (COLUMN_A = 'bb' AND COLUMN_B = 'oo'))
```